# Cannot open module file 'hdf5.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, fortran, hdf5, wsl-2

I'm trying to install DAMASK on WSL2 (Ubuntu20.04)https://damask.mpie.de/bin/view/Installation/SpectralSolver, however, when I want to make spectral solver.

```
(base) admin@DESKTOP-FQ1FRPR:~/damask-2.0.3$ make spectral
```

I met an error as follows,

```
Building Spectral Solver

Fortran Compiler Flags:
 -fopenmp -std=f2008ts -pedantic-errors -O2  -xf95-cpp-input -ffree-line-length-132 -
 fimplicit-none -fmodule-private -Wall -Wextra -Wcharacter-truncation -Wunderflow - 
 Wsuggest-attribute=pure -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wconversion-extra -Wimplicit- 
 procedure -Wno-unused-parameter -ffpe-summary=all  -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8   
 -I/home/fengyx/petsc/include -I/home/fengyx/petsc/arch-linux-c-opt/include

C Compiler Flags:
-O3 -DNDEBUG

Fortran Linker Command:
 /home/admin/petsc/arch-linux-c-opt/bin/mpif90 -Wall -ffree-line-length-0 -Wno-unused- 
 dummy-argument -g -O -fopenmp   -O2  -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup <OBJECTS> -o 
 <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>  -L/home/admin/petsc/arch-linux-c-opt/lib -Wl,- 
 rpath,/home/admin/petsc/arch-linux-c-opt/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 
 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -lpetsc -lHYPRE -lcmumps -ldmumps -lsmumps -lzmumps - 
 lmumps_common -lpord -lpthread -lscalapack -lspqr -lumfpack -lklu -lcholmod -lbtf - 
 lccolamd -lcolamd -lcamd -lamd -lsuitesparseconfig -lsuperlu -lsuperlu_dist -lml - 
 lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lflapack -lfblas -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lchaco -lparmetis -lmetis - 
 ltriangle -lm -lz -lstdc++ -ldl -lmpifort -lmpi -lgfortran -lgcc_s -lquadmath
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/admin/damask-2.0.3/build/spectral
[  1%] Built target PREC
[  3%] Built target C_ROUTINES
[  7%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/QUIT.dir/quit.f90.o
[  7%] Built target SYSTEM_ROUTINES
/home/admin/damask-2.0.3/src/quit.f90:29:5:

   29 |  use hdf5
      |     1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘hdf5.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/QUIT.dir/build.make:63: src/CMakeFiles/QUIT.dir/quit.f90.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:709: src/CMakeFiles/QUIT.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:10: spectral] Error 2
```

Could anyone provide some advices? I will owe my gratitude.

Comment: Did you install hdf5? How?

Comment: In fact, I have installed in this way (`sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev`).

Comment: There seem to be conflicting installs. Can you provide the result of the command `which -a h5fc h5pfc`?

Comment: It shows, `(base) admin@DESKTOP-FQ1FRPR:/mnt/c/Users/Administrator$ which -a h5fc h5pfc
/home/admin/anaconda3/bin/h5fc
/usr/bin/h5fc
/bin/h5fc
/home/admin/anaconda3/bin/h5fc
/usr/local/hdf5/bin/h5fc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to install DAMASK and encountered the same issue. You need to manually install hdf5 from the source code on their page, with the correct compiler, as described in the damask instructions page and "install" text file supplied with hdf5, and correct options. Then reconfigure and remake PETSC with hdf5 folder pointed in configuration instead of --download-hdf5. Then at least this issue will be gone. (I am now struggling with the others).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would you mind giving more details about installation? I am using DAMASK 2.0.3. And I have tried using hdf5 1.8.18 and 1.12 in PETSc configuration, but they still showed the same error. I'm using this '--download hdf5=/installation_directory/' as manual option.

Comment: As I said you will need to install hdf5 manually, by unpacking and compiling the files from their repository, using '--download hdf5=/installation_directory/' will not work. But even if you do, I am not sure it is worth it. Damask 2.x is an obsolete abandoned version, it relies on some old versions of other programs and ultimately I just decided to work with 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You should install libhdf5 using a command like this:

```
apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

If you have manually built that library from source, when compiling the project you need to tell the compiler where to find the HDF5 module. Typically, they reside in the include folder. Locate the module files and add -I/path/to/modules to the compiler options.

Comment: This is the result,

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libhdf5-dev' instead of 'libhdf5-serial-dev'
libhdf5-dev is already the newest version (1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.`
As for the locate 'hdf5.mod', it shows
`/home/admin/anaconda3/include/hdf5.mod
/home/admin/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.4-hb1b8bf9_0/include/hdf5.mod`.
I have also tried to inserted `-I/usr/local/hdf5/include`, it still show the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should just configure petsc with the

`--download-hdf5-fortran-bindings`

configure option and it will work.